# Custom to_html method for a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I have strings like this: #_ Hi all _# and i need to create an output like this:

```
<strong>Hi All</strong>
```

I been googling about parsers in Ruby but i can't find something small and simple to learn how to do this kind of things.

Anyone can help me with documentation or ideas to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Example is very similar to markdown standards. Do you check markdown? You can write your own render rules. http://asciicasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet

Comment: I can't fully understand the source code of Redcarpet... Do you know any link to a example of how to write your own syntax interpreter?

Comment: Do you have any choice in the matter of using which syntax to use? Why not use famous and widely used ones like markdown and textile? Writing syntax interpreter is no trivial task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small and simple:

```
text = "#_ Hi all _#"

html = text.gsub(/#_ /,'<strong>').gsub(/ _#/,'</strong>')
```

Slightly more advanced:

```
tags = {
  '#_ ' => '<strong>', ' _#' => '</strong>',
  '#q ' => '<blockquote>', ' q#' => '</blockquote>'
}

html = text.gsub(/(#_ | _#|#q | q#)/){ tags[$1] }
```

Some ideas for more advanced features if you want:

- enable tag escaping, such as `\#_` means "show this tag as-is"
- ensure a start tag has a corresponding stop tag, such as "#_ ... _#"
- enable nesting, such as "#_ ... #_ ... _# ... _#
- dynamically generate the gsub regexp from the tags hash.
- etc.

Have you seen the Maruku Ruby Markdown parser? I like its codebase, and it has plenty of comments to guide you: https://github.com/bhollis/maruku

Comment: Wow! Thanks... The data is an import from an export from data from decades ago... i just want to clean the text... Thanks i will check the link because now i have data with similar tokens in the borders: °° Hi all °°